# Object stringify to JSON(throws error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I m facing problem when trying to convert object to JSON. I m creating an angular web app.

Below is the json that I converted to object:

```
var array = {
    "game": [{
        "Time (magazine)": [{
            "AARP Bulletin": []
        }, {
            "AARP The Magazine": []
        }]
    }, {
        "Ludwig Wittgenstein": [{
            "Wittgenstein": []
        }, {
            "20th century philosophy": [{
                "16th-century philosophy": [{
                    "19th-century philosophy": []
                }]
            }, {
                "17th-century philosophy": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

and used this method to convert to preferred json structure:

```
function restyle(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
    obj.name = k;
    obj.child = obj[k];
    delete obj[k];
    obj.child.forEach(restyle);
  });
};
```

However, when I tried to console log the array variable after passing through the restyle method. 
I m getting the error

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I tried using JSON.stringfy(array). Same error shows up.

Comment: have you tried toJSON()? Or the other way around JSON.parse(jsonString);

Comment: So...you're creating a circular reference. Use a debugger (there's one built into your browser) to step through the code and see how you're doing that. For a start, constantly overwriting the `obj.child` property is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: The OP is creating a new object structure. It's *that* which they're then converting to JSON -- which is failing because they've created a circular reference.

Comment: Is the error not clear? Or what is your question?

Comment: What is the data structure that you expect `restyle(obj)` to output? Your logic in that method is very flawed.

Comment: https://github.com/jsog/jsog

Comment: I tried this in jsfiddle and I don't see an issue - https://jsfiddle.net/vzpwvpe5/1/

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code as the following in Firebug's console as the following, and it works for me:

```
function restyle(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
    obj.name = k;
    obj.child = obj[k];
    delete obj[k];
    obj.child.forEach(restyle);
  });
};

var array = {
    "game": [{
        "Time (magazine)": [{
            "AARP Bulletin": []
        }, {
            "AARP The Magazine": []
        }]
    }, {
        "Ludwig Wittgenstein": [{
            "Wittgenstein": []
        }, {
            "20th century philosophy": [{
                "16th-century philosophy": [{
                    "19th-century philosophy": []
                }]
            }, {
                "17th-century philosophy": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

restyle(array);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

I get the following as the console output:

```
{"name":"game","child":[{"name":"Time (magazine)","child":[{"name":"AARP Bulletin","child":[]},{"name":"AARP The Magazine","child":[]}]},{"name":"Ludwig Wittgenstein","child":[{"name":"Wittgenstein","child":[]},{"name":"20th century philosophy","child":[{"name":"16th-century philosophy","child":[{"name":"19th-century philosophy","child":[]}]},{"name":"17th-century philosophy","child":[]}]}]}]}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?